# Safari displaying the binary code instead of downloading Adobe air application

Tags: air, safari, download

I'm using Adobe Air 1.5 with Safari 4.0.3 on Mac OS Snow Leopard. When the browser attempts to download the Air file, binary code is displayed in the browser instead of downloading the Air application. Firefox has no problems downloading this Air application for either the Mac or the PC.
Also safari on windows correctly downloads the binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added proper MIME type on server for client browser to recognize AIR application ?Make sure its the following

```
 AddType application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip .air
```

reference
http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/air/1_5_1/releasenotes_developers.html